# Decrypting External Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, external-hdd, decryption

A couple months back I had an old 350 gb Transcend external drive I forgot about and on a whim, installed Ubuntu on it. After using it for a couple months I decided to ditch Windows all together and installed Ubuntu on my laptop permanently, a decision I have no regrets over.

Now, the problem. There are some files on the external drive I want, the drive is encrypted. When I plug the drive in, it mounts, in the drive is an icon,
`Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop`, when I double click it, a window pops up and closes so quickly I can not see what it is, I assumed it would prompt me for a password or something but it doesn't.

I have searched to try and find a solution, I am currently digging through my copy of the Linux Bible and other resources but have so far come up empty. I don't have the skills yet, but I'm working on it, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you connect it to your computer (internally or via eSATA or USB), you should be able to boot from it again. Do you remember the password/passphrase? Otherwise you have bad luck. It should also be possible to decrypt it manually without booting from it (as long as you remember the password/passphrase).

Comment: Find out which command is executed by the `.desktop` file: open it with a text editor or execute `cat /path/to/file.desktop` in a terminal. There should be a line beginning with `Exec=`, that is the command that is run when you double click it. In a terminal, navigate to your external drive and run the command. Now you should be able to see what is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I upgraded the system to 18.04 LTS and I was able to open it without any problems by clicking the .Desktop icon and entering the passphrase. Thanks again for the help.